# How to keep notes with files in Git

Tags: git

I am trying to do something unusual (?) with Git --- storing my multimedia files and photos and some pdf files with Git. I want to keep some meta data with each file (e.g., with a photo: I want to keep some sort of caption with it; with a pdf file: some information about what the file is about for ease of searching later on). In svn you can use svn properties to store metadata about a file (I think). How do I do the same in Git? Haven't been able to find any *easy* way! `git notes` looked promising, but it only associates notes with objects (commits). I want notes with individual files.

Update: I do *not* want to keep a separate file for metadata of files/paths! :-) I want to keep the information with the file/path somehow. Like svn properties (`svn propset caption "In the Golden Gate" foo.jpg`). To be more precise, when I move files around (`git mv path1/file path2/file`), I don't want to have to worry about keeping the metadata file up to date... the metadata should move with the file.

Answer (score 2):

Just keep in separate files, and do a `pre-commit` hook to fix them.

You can detect renamed file (in index/cache) using `git diff --cached -M --summary`

```
[flames]$ git diff --cached -M --summary
rename a => b (100%)
```

then do fancy stuffs (i suggest using perl, but I use sed here just for demo)

```
[flames]$ git diff --cached -M --summary | \
> grep rename | \
> sed 's/^ rename \(.*\) => \(.*\) (.*/s\/^\1$\/\2\//'
s/^a$/b/
```

use this regex on your note file (not tested):

```
#!/bin/sh
REGEX="`git diff --cached -M --summary | \
     grep rename | \
     sed 's/^ rename \(.*\) => \(.*\) (.*/s\/^\1$\/\2\//'
    `"
sed -i -e "$REGEX"  note-file
git add note-file
exit 0
```

---

A easier to parse format is the `--raw` format.

```
[flames]$ git diff --cached -M --raw
:100644 100644 b53a58b... 3f063ab... M  wxyz
:100644 100644 e69de29... e69de29... R100       a       b
```

Just search for R on the 5th column. man diffcore(7) for details. This is leave as an exercise for reader.

Comment: J-16 SDiZ: I am not familiar with this... can you give me some pointers on how to go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd need a solution outside of Git that can handle editing metadata of various filetypes. Either that or you can create a text file for every single piece of media you want metadata for, but that sounds impractical.

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding the question? Is it you want to have a sort of short description of the file while browsing in git?

Comment: Cameron Malek: Updated the question. Thanks for a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at gibak:  https://github.com/mfp/gibak